# Activate lazy variable by name

Tags: scala, reflection, lazy-evaluation

Let's say I have a case class with a lazy member

```
case class Person(name: String, surname: String) {
  lazy val initials: String = name(0) + "." + surname(0) + "."
}
```

And I have a universal function which converts it into Map

```
def getCCParams(cc: AnyRef) =
  cc.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map { f =>
    f.setAccessible(true)
    f.getName -> f.get(cc)
  }.toMap
```

now I create a person and get its values

```
val JohnSmith = Person("John", "Smith")
val res = getCCParams(JohnSmith)
println(res)
```

thus i get result

```
HashMap(initials -> null, name -> John, surname -> Smith)
```

initials equal null because it was not called.
Is there any way to activate lazy value inside `getCCParams` function? The list of lazy members I can pass as a parameter

```
def getCCParams(cc: AnyRef, lazyMembers: List[String] = List("initials")) = ...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lazy vals are initialized when the accessor method is called the first time. So maybe you could just call these methods instead of trying to get directly to fields?

```
def getCCParams(cc: AnyRef) = {
  val clazz = cc.getClass
  clazz.getDeclaredFields.flatMap { f =>
    Try(clazz.getMethod(f.getName)) //get the accessor method by name of field
      .toOption
      .map(m => f.getName -> m.invoke(cc))
  }.toMap
}
```

Result: 
`Map(initials -> J.S., name -> John, surname -> Smith)`

Answer (score 4):

Krzysztof's answer works because `lazy val initials = "J.S."` expands to something like

```
lazy var initials: String = _;
var bitmap$0: Boolean = _;
private def initials$lzycompute(): String = {
  if (!bitmap$0)
  {
    initials = ("J.S.": String);
    bitmap$0 = true
  };
  initials
};
lazy def initials(): String =
  if (!bitmap$0)
    initials$lzycompute()
  else
    initials;
```

where we see corresponding public `initials` as well as private `initials$lzycompute` methods which actually sets `var initials`.

Comment: I've seen function in your answer, now it disappears. Something was wrong with it?

Comment: @DmitryReutov It seemed to work, however Krzysztof's solution is cleaner.

Comment: anyway thanx for explanation, it was quite interesting

Answer (score 2):

Thanx a lot Krzysztof and Mario, finally i did like this

```
def getCCParams(cc: AnyRef, lazyFields: Set[String] = Set()) =
  {
    val cl = cc.getClass
    val pairs = cl.getDeclaredFields flatMap { f: Field =>
      f.getName match {
        case name: String if name.startsWith("bitmap$") => None
        case name: String =>
          if (lazyFields.contains(name)) {
            cl.getMethod(name).invoke(cc)
          }
          f.setAccessible(true)
          Some(name -> f.get(cc))
      }
    }

    pairs.toMap
  }


val JohnSmith = Person("John", "Smith")
val res = getCCParams(JohnSmith, Set("initials"))
```

it allows to choose which members i want to activate, which i dont, and allows not include bitmap$ to result